# IE Rending issue

Tags: internet-explorer

We set a URL to view log file (.txt) file for our client. Some of our log file gave error with IE but works fine with chrome and firefox. here is what we wrote in text file

```
2010-10-15 08:34:18,867 [1] DEBUG - 

UserHostAddress 198.96.178.33 
UserHostName 198.96.178.33 
UserAgent Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
10/15/2010 8:34:18 AM 
Request <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><SearchDetailsRequest><Credentials><UserId>factiva</UserId><Password>facpassword123</Password></Credentials><SearchTerms><RequestID value="AML1010150002920"><Record type="2" SearchID="1"><ExactMatch>0</ExactMatch><Name>IBM</Name><FirstName></FirstName><MiddleName></MiddleName><LastName></LastName><CountryCodes></CountryCodes></Record><Record type="2" SearchID="2"><ExactMatch>0</ExactMatch><Name>CFX Holdings</Name><FirstName></FirstName><MiddleName></MiddleName><LastName></LastName><CountryCodes></CountryCodes></Record><PageNo>1</PageNo><MaxResultstoReturn>100</MaxResultstoReturn><SortResultBy>Name</SortResultBy></RequestID><DateTime>10/15/2010 08:34:07</DateTime></SearchTerms></SearchDetailsRequest></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: Can you at least specify the error that IE shows?

Comment: If you save this content in notepad and try to open with IE, it gives

Comment: error The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource

Comment: The fact that your last comment was truncated when you first posted it should give you a hint about what's happening to IE :)

Comment: When you save above code to text file and try to open it with IE, it gives error that "he XML page cannot be displayed Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource " It works with Chrome and Firefox though.

Comment: If someone can help, i can set complete text file which i am not able to open with IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Content-Type header being sent ([Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) may be useful). We've had issues with naming our log files ".log" and had to set IIS to serve them as text/plain for IE to display them correctly.

If you're serving them up through a script, you should be able to set the Content Type in the script.

When I open a .txt file with the above contents in IE, it worked fine, so it might be something specific to your PC rather than the server. There's [some info here on MIME Type detection in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - one of the things it does is reads content, so it might be seeing the XML and assuming the whole doc is supposed to be XML.